# How to filter a (or all) joined table's rows by the current logged in user in django?

Tags: django

My creation is a basic project about ticketing, users and assets. It's a typical application that companies have to keep a list of who has what and what issues are occurring.

So far I have (models):

```
**** Tickets ******************

class Ticket(models.Model):    
    category = models.ForeignKey('TicketCategory')    
    issue = models.CharField(max_length=100)    
    user = models.ForeignKey('Users', blank=True,null=True,related_name="tickets")
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

**** Users *********************

class Users(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    business = models.ForeignKey('Business', blank=True, null=True,related_name="users")
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'
        verbose_name_plural = "users" 
        ordering = ["lastname"]

**** Assets *********************

class Assets(models.Model):
    serial = models.CharField(unique=False, max_length=100)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey('Users', blank=True, null=True, related_name="assets")
    location = models.ForeignKey('AssetLocation', blank=False, null=False, related_name="assets")
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I have stripped them down a bit to exclude the useless info. There are others also like AssetsLocations, Categories etc., all of them in the same pattern - the owner is added in the end as a Foreign Key.

I have created some form of authentication, so every logged in user will have his own tickets, assets, and users (employees actually). Filtering is needed so the data of each user ONLY are displayed after every successful authentication.

I am using CBVs and override the get_queryset to enable filtering by the user currently logged in:

Views.py

```
class TicketList(ListView):
    template_name = 'assets/ticket_list.html' 
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Ticket.objects.filter(owner_id=user.id).select_related('user','asset','category') 
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TicketList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['totalTickets'] = self.get_queryset().count()
        context['tickets'] = self.get_queryset().select_related('user','asset','category')
        return context
```

Everything works successfully and only logged_in user's data are shown. Then I am trying to create a new Ticket:

```
class TicketCreate(CreateView):
    fields = [ 'category', 'issue', 'user']
    template_name = 'assets/ticket_form.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Ticket.objects.filter(owner_id=user.id)
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.owner_id = self.request.user.id
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
    success_url = reverse_lazy('ticket_list')
```

I am getting everything posted in the form template by using `{{ form.category }}`, `{{ form.issue }}` etc. The issue I am facing is that the drop-down boxes displayed in the form, for example the {{ form.user }} should be displaying only the users where user.owner = self.request.user.id, in simple words: the users that the owner created. Instead of it, all the users in the database are displayed.

Isn't it obvious which is the question :) ?

Comment: I am not sure how are you sending data to templates about user.

Comment: it would be easier to just create a model manager, but I don't think you can access requests there.

Comment: @ruddra what do you mean ? what do you want me to show ?